# Bitmap being null / imagepath not existing

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I have multiple Activities that are supposed to work on one image that is taken through an Intent as described here
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
I then have a path to my image, which I use to access the photo and manipulate it (changing size, colors)
But when I try to create a Bitmap from the path, it always give Errors like

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
```

I have the imagePath saved in a private variable, and pass it in a Bundle betweeen the activities, which works fine the first time. When I pass it the same way to the third activity, the abobe error shows.

Here's a bit of my code to scale the image before putting it in the ImageView:

```
public class scaleImage {
static Bitmap setPic(ImageView mImageView, String mCurrentPhotoPath) {

    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    //bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return bitmap;
}
}
```

The function in the first Activity that creates a file that the image is saved to (like in the example):

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    imageFileName = image.getName();
    return image;
}
```

The second Activity gets the imagePath through a Bundle when called and passes it to the third one the same way like this:

```
void callPictureScalerActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConvertToGrayscale.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("imagePath", mCurrentPhotoPath);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The third Activity tries get a Bitmap from the imagepath which isn't working anymore. (Have to do this not in onCreate since the size of the imageView is not known yet):

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(focus);
    scaleImage.setPic((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scalablePicture), photoPath);

}
```

So I'm wondering, does the file for the image get deleted after calling more then one Activity or is the fault somewhere else? At this point I'm clueless at what other way I should access the Image.

**Edit**: The error above appears in the line where I'm trying to get the Bitmap from the path:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
```

so it's an error that occurs in the decodeFile function, which I can't look into.

Also the third Activity is called when a Button is pressed in the second, calling the callPictureScalerActivity function.

The photo is saved with following function:

```
void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.w("Error", "Error creating the image file");

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

I know the photo is saved since I looked up the path from mCurrentPhotoPath.

Comment: Can you post the code to launch the third activity?

Comment: It looks like you're creating a temp file, but never actually writing any data to it. In `createImageFile()` you never write anything to `File image`

Comment: `java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference`. That is the error you posted. So where is the code with . toCharArray() ? You should of course only post code which causes the error.

Comment: Use Glide or Picasso and don't waste your time.

Comment: I've edited my question. If it helps, I can post a link to my github with the whole project

Comment: @Divers I'm only trying to access the Image I took via an Intent by its path. I didn't believe it to be so complicated to have to rely on other libraries